# error when using which.min() with ave()

Tags: r

I have some data, much of which is `NA`.
For simplicity, let's say it looks like this:

```
x = c(NA, 3, 4, 3.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 5)
bins = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
```

I'm using `ave( )` and `which.min( )` to get the minimum value for each bin type:

```
ave(x, segments, FUN = which.min)
```

But I get the error:

```
    Error in `split<-.default`(`*tmp*`, g, value = lapply(split(x, g), FUN)) : 
  replacement has length zero
```

The reason this is happening (I think) is because bin # 3 only has `NA` values. When this is rectified, the error disappears. I could just use a function like:

```
 ave(x, segments, FUN = function(xx){
  if(all(is.na(xx))){
    return(NA)
  } else {
    xx = which.min(xx)
    return(xx)
  }}
  )
```

But:

1) that is hacky as heck. And

2) `which.min(c(NA, NA, NA))` does not cause an error, nor does `ave(c(NA, NA, NA), c(1, 1, 1), FUN=mean)` - so what's going on that I'm missing?

--> Anybody have an idea of why this error happens / the best way to get around it?

Cheers.

Comment: because `which.min(c(NA, NA))` is `integer(0)` and `length(integer(0))` is 0, hence replacement has length 0, and ave expects the same output length as input length

Comment: your version is pretty short and non-hacky imo. you could also do `ave(x, bins, FUN = function(xx) if (length(yy <- which.min(xx))) yy else NA)`

Comment: Ahh, that's why. Thanks.